# Lock screen when proximity sensor is covered

Tags: lock-screens, proximity-sensor

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Jelly Bean. I would like, for, my screen to lock if proximity sensor is covered (for instance, when it is in my pocket).

How can I do that?

I am searching for an app as I have not found anything within the standard menu.

Comment: Does the proximity sensor (assuming NFC) work on pockets? I thought it only worked with other NFC capable objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Smart Cover](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=smart.cover), [Cover Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.omd.coverlock), [Simple Cover Lock [Beta]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.zalio.android.cso) and others on Google Play. You can probably find other apps that maybe are better for you by just looking at the 'similar' apps section on Google Play.

Comment: Simple Cover Lock [Beta] does the job. And it's free.